# Magento Related Product don't show up

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the related products block to show up on my product detail page.
I have the folling code in the respective .phtml file

```
<?php

<?php echo "Related product block"?>
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or')  ?>&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="selectAllRelated(this); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('select all') ?></a></p>
    <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo     $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('block-related', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
    Event.observe(elem, 'click', addRelatedToProduct)
});

var relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
function selectAllRelated(txt){
    if (relatedProductsCheckFlag == false) {
        $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
            elem.checked = true;
        });
        relatedProductsCheckFlag = true;
        txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('unselect all') ?>";
    } else {
        $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
            elem.checked = false;
        });
        relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
        txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('select all') ?>";
    }
    addRelatedToProduct();
}

function addRelatedToProduct(){
    var checkboxes = $$('.related-checkbox');
    var values = [];
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked) values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    if($('related-products-field')){
        $('related-products-field').value = values.join(',');
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The echo above the code shows up on my page. Which of course proves that i implemented the block correctly.

Just everything in the if-statement doesn't show.

I spend some time looking for solutions and i tried rebuilding the indexes and my related product is visible on the frontend.

Anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your 4 line:

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize() > 0 ? true : false) ?>
```

Try it.

Comment: awesome it's working but i dont get checkbox to select product. have you any idea about this why checkbox not appear in related product ?

Comment: this code of checkbox not working for me. please check this 

<?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 3):

Magento will always return a low number or 0 for the condition:

```
$this->getItems()->getSize()
```

if some/all of the related products are in the user's cart, and consequently items will appear as though they are missing.

To prevent this behaviour, duplicate the core Magento 'Related' class:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php
```

to local:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php
```

Then comment out the following lines in the if statement:

```
if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
    //mod - show all related products, even if they have been added to the cart
    //Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
    //    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
    //);
    $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
}
```

Comment: While this kind of override is not recommended, and it's worth the time to create the override in a custom module, this answer did solve my problem. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code type

```
var_dump($this->getItems()->getSize()) // does this print NUll, False or > 0
```

If the code above print NULL or false or less than 1, then do

```
print_r($this->getItems());
```

If none of the above print the information you expected then check your block getItems() method

Also where is the closing IF for `if($this->getItems()->getSize()):`